# Настрока test cover Codeclimate на Github Actions Python

Tags: python, github-actions, code-coverage

Пытаюсь разобраться каким образом настроить code climate test coverage. Воркфлоу работает, но при добавлении блока

> ```
>   - uses: paambaati/codeclimate-action@v2.2.4
>     env:
>       CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID: 945dfb58a832d233a3caeb84e3e6d3be212e8c7abcb48117fce63b9adcb43647
>     with:
>       coverageCommand: yarn coverage
> ```

Возникает ошибка:

> Error: Could not find file
> '/home/runner/work/_actions/_temp_6c20f9ea-3c52-4aa9-9dc7-e70580c85c7f/_staging/paambaati-codeclimate-action-478c649/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/.bin/semver'.

Бейджик в Readme.md не показывает процент покрытия. Исходя из [документации](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/github-actions-test-coverage) не ясно каим образом это настроить.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых `CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID` надо спрятать в `Secrets` вашего репозитория

Во-вторых команда для определения покрытия `coverageCommand` у вас указана для **JS**. Для  **Python** она будет другая, зависит от того как вы работаете с тестами, например `pytest coverage`